# VBA dim long throwing error 6

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and was hoping anyone could help me understand why the "ean" line trows run-time error 6:

```
Sub RemovalOf_Barcodes()   
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
Dim i As Long    
Dim temp As Long    
Dim ean As Long    
Dim y As Long    


i = 2    
Do While Cells(i, 2) <> ""   
i = i + 1   
Loop   
i = i - 1   

For y = 2 To i   
    ean = Cells(y, 2).Value   
Next y
```

I have also tried using below

```
For y = 2 To i
    temp  =  Cells(y, 2).Value
    ean = Clng(temp)   
Next y
```

I appericate all help I can get :)

Comment: What is the value in `Cells(y,2)`?

Comment: It is a 10+ number (I.E 3014260014155)

Comment: try to save it as a `String`, not as numeric type.

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that an EAN number is typically 13 digits in length and you're attempting to store this in a `Long`

```
Dim ean As Long
```

If you have to store this as numeric value *(why!? Are you doing math on it?)* ,try storing it in a `Double`. Provided it's a normal EAN with no decimal places, I think a `Double` will work.

```
Dim ean As Double
```

**But as @Vityata suggests, `String` is better suited for this purpose.**

Comment: Will this work to compare to another cell that uses a custom number format?
I'm trying to compare if (example) 3014260014155 is in a another cell that uses number format #0

Comment: If you're comparing two EANs, load them both into strings. You're currently loading the `.Value` of the cell - so it's ignoring any formatting. If you treat both cells in the same way then you should be able to like-for-like compare. It's a wider question though - we'd really need to see what's in the cells and how they are formatted to give you a definitive answer - so that would best be presented as a new question.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking that way too, i have used CStr() for that cell and see if this works. Otherwise i will load them into seperate sheets and convert them to the same format. Thanks for the help!